# DataTables warning: table id=tablausuarios - Ajax error

Tags: php, ajax, json, datatables, laravel-8

estoy tratando de mostrar una tabla a través de ajax y laravel pero me da este error al cargar la pagina
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi codigo tengo la siguiente estructura

```
<table class="table table-bordered mt-4" id="tablausuarios">
     <thead>
         <tr>
                
           <th>Nombre</th>
                
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section('js')
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src=" {{asset('js/usuarios.js')}} "></script>
@stop
```

En mi usuarios.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tablaUsuarios=$('#tablausuarios').DataTable({
    
    "ajax":
        " {{route('tablas.tablausuario')}} ",
    "columns":[
       
        {data:'name'},  
    ]
});
});
```

En mi archivo web.php tengo

```
route::get('admin/usuarios', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController@index');
route::get('tabla/usuarios', 'App\Http\Controllers\TablasController@tablausuarios')- 
>name('tablas.tablausuario');
```

y en mi TablasController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
Use App\Models\User;

class TablasController extends Controller
  {
    public function tablausuarios(){
    //$usuarios= DB::select('select * from sp_mostrar_usuarios()');
    $usuarios=User::select('name')->get();
    return datatables()->of($usuarios)->toJson();
  }
}
```

Si entro a la ruta de la tabla puedo ver lo que trae como información Json pero al momento de pintar la tabla en la ruta de los usuarios me da el error, esto es lo que me trae en Json

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":[{"name":"andres oberto","profile_photo_url":"https:\/\/ui-avatars.com\/api\/?name=andres+oberto&amp;color=7F9CF5&amp;background=EBF4FF"}],"input":[]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo al [enlace sugerido en el error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7) el problema es por la ruta. Supongo que usuarios.js no es interpretado por el sistema de plantillas y, por lo tanto, queda simplemente " {{route('tablas.tablausuario')}} ".

En la plantilla podrías crear un script donde definas la ruta antes de incluir `usuarios.js` y no pongas espacios internos, porque *"facilitan"* la lectura pero pueden provocar errores:

```
<table class="table table-bordered mt-4" id="tablausuarios">
     <thead>
         <tr>
                
           <th>Nombre</th>
                
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section('js')
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Define la ruta
let rutaTabla = "{{route('tablas.tablausuario')}}";
</script>
<script src="{{asset('js/usuarios.js')}}"></script>
@stop
```

Después, en `usuarios.js` usas esa variable para especificar la ruta:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let tablaUsuarios=$('#tablausuarios').DataTable({
        "ajax": rutaTabla,
        "columns": [
            {data: 'name'},  
        ]
    });
});
```

Aunque este punto no es parte de la pregunta, por la estructura del objeto JSON esperada, es probable que debas cambiar el origen de datos:

```
        "columns":[
            {data.data: 'name'},  
        ]
```

Realiza tus pruebas y revisa la consola para ver si hay errores.

Comment: Hola realice lo que me dijiste y si es eso, al tener un archivo js externo no me leía la ruta ya que no se encontraba en una plantilla blade, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mi proyecto es Laravel + Datatables.

Este error me aparecía en producción pero no en local, por si a alguien le sirve lo solucioné cambiando las rutas a Datatables:

en config/app.php esta línea:

`'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,`

la cambié por esta:

`'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\DataTables::class,`

y en los controllers cambié en todos la ruta:

`use Yajra\DataTables\Facades\Datatables;`

por esta:

`use Yajra\DataTables\Datatables;`

y funcionó, espero que le sirva a alguien porque me estaba volviendo loco.